# nginx is not directing from 80 to 8080

Tags: nginx

I'm running Tomcat on port 8080 and I'm able to hit it at :8080. I've set-up nginx using [step 9 in this guide](https://www.atlantic.net/vps-hosting/how-to-setup-tomcat-with-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-on-ubuntu/) so my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/tomcat.conf` looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-error.log;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass       "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
        }
}
```

But when I hit the IP address I'm met with the standard "Welcome to nginx" page.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: It's in `sites-available`, but is it linked into `sites-enabled`?

Comment: Yes, I ran `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/tomcat.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was supposed to delete the `default` symlink in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.